# How do you animate the labels for a diagram in Blender?

Tags: animation, text-object

I'm making this animation and the parts need to be labelled.

This means that the lines from the label to each part will be animated and so will the text be animated.

two examples showing what I'm trying to achieve, [here](http://vimeo.com/65492097) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2HNXaw7Fv8).

However, please remember that the lines will have to have an entrance in some manner. This is the context: [image: animation]

This is the type of animations I wish for the lines: http://vimeo.com/27093074
Current [.blend file](http://www.filedropper.com/xtruder_2).

Comment: This reads as too much of a tutorial request to me. What have you tried?

Comment: @iKlsR I've already made a text block, but I don't know how to make the text clear to the camera (the same angle) and how to make the lines and animate them. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: I thing if you create basic line and change that line to curve and give that curve some thinkness by curve circle it could work and animated with empties  ,or animated planes with ik bones could work too,this is tutorial question Google

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3171/599

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create animated lines like in the [video you linked](http://vimeo.com/27093074), you could use [*Curves*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves) and animate the [*start* and *end* bevel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Geometry) factors. (see this [related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3171/599))

1. Add a curve object
2. Set the *Fill* to *Full* in *Object Data > Shape*

   [image]
3. Increase the *depth* in *Object data > Geometry > Bevel*:

   [image]
4. Animate the start and end bevel factors by right clicking and selecting *insert keyframe*, or pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over it.

E.g. by animating the *Start bevel factor* from 1 to 0:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to have any object always facing the camera when you are animating it is to use a Track-To constraint.

[image]

To keep a line between the label and the target subject point a hook modifier can be used.

[image]

While in edit mode you have the option to Assign the modifier to a point of a curve object or vertices for mesh objects. The shortcut for applying hooks is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. If you select the target and then shift select the object to be deformed and go into edit mode you can choose to attach the hook to the selected object.