# Animate 2D Circle being drawn

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I am trying to get the effect seen in the answer for this question [How do you animate the labels for a diagram in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/how-do-you-animate-the-labels-for-a-diagram-in-blender/5400#5400) to work on a circle. I created a new curve -> Circle, set it to 2D, set fill to "none", increased the bevel depth and resolution, and then animated the bevel factor, but to no avail. How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: related:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/how-to-make-a-circular-swipe/16052#16052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the circle, from **Shift A > Curve > Circle**, go to the Object Data panel and set **Fill to** **Full**. Then, increase the values for **Depth** and **Resolution** under bevel.

Then , go to the modifiers and add a **Build** modifier. Afterwards,add a value of 1 for **Start** and keep length at 100. When you press play your circle will be drawn :)

Answer (score 5):

A Curve>Circle is not going to work for what you want to do, a circle is a closed path and you need an open one.

Create a curve and make the circle so that the start and end point of the curve are in the same place, but do not close the path.
[image]

Then animating the start or end of the bevel factor should work fine.

[image]