# Can you add geometry to a mesh over time (frames) with Python?

Tags: python, mesh

I'd like to create an effect similar to a plant growing over time. Imagine, as the plant grows, it sprouts new leafs and shoots.

I know I can generate a mesh using Python, but can I add geometry to the mesh over time and if so how?

Comment: There are many possible ways of going about this without python,  e.g. the [build modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Build), animated [bevel start/end](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3171/599) factor, animated objects with boolean modifiers, etc.

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks, I'm looking to create a complex model (think Ivy or vines), would the methods you suggest be able to achieve this?

Comment: Hm.. Not sure without some experimentation. However it looks like someone already came up with at least one solution: http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/30/tutorial-growing-ivygen-animation-in-blender/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Sapling addon to create a tree. The addon needs to be enabled first in the *User Preferences*

[image]

After the settings were adjusted.

Convert it from curve to mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

Add a [*Build Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Build) to the stem and another one to the leaves, you might want to add a few more loop cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to the stem so that the segments are displayed one by one.

To let the plant grow scale it down say 10% on frame 1, 50% on frame 10, 100% on frame 20
Set the Build modifiers start frame to 20 and 30.

Result:

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/32974)